# combination with missing or mismathes in r

Tags: r, dataframe, permutation, combinations

I have to create unique combination while allowing some mismatches. The following is an example:

```
set.seed (1234)
dataf <- data.frame (var1 = sample( c("A", "B", "-"),20, replace = T),
            var2 = sample( c("A"),20, replace = T),
            var3 = sample( c("B", "B", "B", "-"),20, replace = T),
            var4 = sample( c("A","A", "A",  "-"),20, replace = T),
            var5 = sample( c("A", "B", "A", "A", "-"),20, replace = T)
            )
 dataf
```

Rules:

(1) Generate Unique combinations:

```
     A B     A  B  B   - combination 1
    A  A     A  B  B    - combination 2
    B  B     B  A  A    - combination 3 
   so on ...
```

(2)  Allow one (can be n) mismatch to create a category. For example:

```
A   B    A  B  B
A   A    A  B  B
B   A    A  B  B
B   A    B  B  B 
B   A    A  B  A
```

are same as there a single mismatch at different variables.

(3)  "-" indicates missing values, can be treated as similar way as integers in matching means that one mismatch allowed.

```
A   B    A  B  B
 A   -    A  B  B
 A   B    A  -  B
```

However if there are two missing values then combination is declared unknown (-)

```
 A   B    A  B  B
 A   -    A  -  B
 A   B    A  -  -
```

The following is workout for the above data.

```
    var1 var2 var3 var4 var5       comb
1     A    A    B    -    -       -

2     B    A    B    A    A        1
3     B    A    B    A    A        1
4     B    A    B    A    A        1
5     -    A    B    A    A        1
6     B    A    B    A    -        1

7     A    A    B    A    B        2
8     A    A    B    A    B        2

9     B    A    B    A    A        1

10    B    A    -    A    -        -

11    -    A    B    A    A        1

12    B    A    B    -    -        -

13    A    A    B    A    A        2

14    -    A    B    -    A        -

15    A    A    B    A    A        2
16    -    A    B    A    A        2
17    A    A    B    A    B        2

18    A    A    -    A    A        3

19    A    A    B    A    B        2

20    A    A    -    A    A        3
```

Any idea ?

Comment: just a small idea, you can merge var1 to var5 to create new factor - for example (AABAA etc), then you can work on this variable...I am not sure how we can work on single mismatches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. The idea is create a distance matrix, so you can cluster your data into groups of rows that have a zero distance among them.

First, let's remove (temporarily) the rows that have two or more dashes:

```
two.dashes <- apply(dataf, 1, function(x)sum(x == '-') >= 2)
subdata <- dataf[!two.dashes,]
```

Then, let's compute a distance matrix.

```
mydist.fun <- function(i, j, x = subdata) {
   row.i <- x[i, ]
   row.j <- x[j, ]
   idx   <- row.i != '-' & row.j != '-'
   sum(row.i[idx] != row.j[idx])
}
rows.idx  <- seq_len(nrow(subdata))
rows.dist <- as.dist(outer(rows.idx, rows.idx, Vectorize(mydist.fun)))
```

Then, let's use clustering to group your data. I am using a complete hierarchical clustering and cutting it at `height = 0`, i.e., it creates groups of points that all have a distance of zero among them.

```
hc <- hclust(rows.dist)
members <- cutree(hc, h = 0)
```

Let's put everything together:

```
comb <- rep('-', nrow(dataf))
comb[!two.dashes] <- members
dataf$comb <- comb
dataf
#    var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 comb
# 1     A    A    B    -    -    -
# 2     B    A    B    A    A    1
# 3     B    A    B    A    A    1
# 4     B    A    B    A    A    1
# 5     -    A    B    A    A    1
# 6     B    A    B    A    -    1
# 7     A    A    B    A    B    2
# 8     A    A    B    A    B    2
# 9     B    A    B    A    A    1
# 10    B    A    -    A    -    -
# 11    -    A    B    A    A    1
# 12    B    A    B    -    -    -
# 13    A    A    B    A    A    3
# 14    -    A    B    -    A    -
# 15    A    A    B    A    A    3
# 16    -    A    B    A    A    1
# 17    A    A    B    A    B    2
# 18    A    A    -    A    A    3
# 19    A    A    B    A    B    2
# 20    A    A    -    A    A    3
```

This is exposing contradictions in your expected output. For example, row 7 and 13 should not belong to the same group. Also, there are rows with a single dash that could go to different groups, e.g. row 16.

Comment: thank you for interesting way to do it. so here the play is value of h, to allow more or less mismatches... 7 and 13 should be in the same group as they have only one mismatch ...

Comment: Also creating distance matrix is slow process when I have 1000 individuals

Comment: On one side, you say that 7 and 13 should be in the same category because they only have one mismatch, on the other side you distinguish between combination 1 (ABABB) and combination 2 (AAABB). I don't think my output suffers from such inconsistencies.